# How Medium handle Paste link and embedded link

Tags: embedded-video

**I'm talking about How They Handle? does they store video in their hosting?**

I saw from inception mode that's When i pasted you-tube link than it's doesn't fetch from you-tube directly iframe Url be:-

> https://medium.com/media/Token_Number

This is also same for embedded code, when we paste it's url change,

What that means?

how it's work?

can any one explain logic behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Medium.com doesn't store embedded YouTube videos at their webspaces. They're producing an iframe-container instead and integrated the preview image from youtube.
You can see it in the source code what they're doing with f.e. an integrated YouTube video:

```
<div class="iframeContainer"><iframe data-width="854" data-height="480" src="/media/61e47d89d00c7ba29a1a928fb043bfd9" data-media-id="61e47d89d00c7ba29a1a928fb043bfd9" data-thumbnail="https://i.embed.ly/1/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FYGODvbhLx_A%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=a19fcc184b9711e1b4764040d3dc5c07" allowfullscreen="" width="700" height="393" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```